# Text inside each html row or column color to change one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a help to allow number from 10 to 21 to change font color to white one by one and keep on looping. something like when we are inside lift- it keep in glowing  floor number as and when it reach that floor.

```css
.grid {
    max-width: var(--wrapper);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--noOfColumns), 1fr);
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
    /* If the content is taller then the box will grow to fit. This is only going to work if the column value is 1fr*/
    grid-auto-rows: var(--rh);
    grid-row-gap: var(--gutter);
    margin: var(--gutter);
    background-color: #555e65;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div >10</div>
    <div>14</div>
    <div >18</div>
    <div>17</div>
    <div>18</div>
    <div>19</div>
    <div >20</div>
    <div>21</div>
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you just want to change the color of the number all in one go? Or do you want to change the first number, wait 1 second and then change the next and so on?

Comment: ask your qustion in more general way . so it appear in more google search . then pepole will like to answer your qustion for the benfit of all developers

Comment: sorry yes i want to wait for like after every 10 second the next number color change to white in sequence manner and previous number color turn back to original color of number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.grid {
  max-width: var(--wrapper);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--noOfColumns), 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  /* If the content is taller then the box will grow to fit. This is only going to work if the column value is 1fr*/
  grid-auto-rows: var(--rh);
  grid-row-gap: var(--gutter);
  margin: var(--gutter);
  background-color: #555e65;
}

@keyframes changeColor {
 from{color:red}
 to{color:red};
}

.animate {
  color: blue;
  transition: color .3s ease;
  animation: changeColor 10s;
}

.animate:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: .01s;
}

.animate:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 10s;
}

.animate:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 20s;
}
.animate:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 30s;
}

.animate:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 40s;
}

.animate:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 50s;
}
.animate:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 60s;
}

.animate:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 70s;
}

.animate:nth-child(9) {
  animation-delay: 80s;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="animate gr">10</div>
  <div class="animate">14</div>
  <div class="animate">18</div>
  <div class="animate">17</div>
  <div class="animate">18</div>
  <div class="animate">19</div>
  <div class="animate">20</div>
  <div class="animate">21</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your code for a better understanding!

Comment: Can i increase the font size with color as well and make it  start again once it reach last number